# End user adoption/understanding

Tags: workflow, deployment, user-management

I tend to encounter this problem quite a bit. Usually the project team has an idea and we build a few features, alerts, dashboards, etc.

Yet, I often see that end users do not always understand everything we built. I have noticed that my notes/guides tend to be somewhat technical, but maybe I should build some sort of knowledge base that tells the user 'alert 1' does XYZ.

Does anyone else see this problem? How do you tackle it?

Comment: Might be worth checking out [my trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/mytrailhead). They're just custom trailheads, but having a method to create "tutorials" for the various features your developers make is a good way to ensure full coverage (via badges, completion %) of those features.

Answer (score 2):

Your question quite a broad, but here are some approaches to tackle this situation.

1. If you have an idea then post this idea in chatter and get a vote on this idea. Also, you should make sure users are adopting Chatter quite well, otherwise, ideas will not reach to the broader audience.
2. Before actual implementation, you need to engage your user on what you are planning to implement and how business will get benefited (either by, improvement of productivity, cost etc.)
3. Show and Tell approach - You can create a mock application to show customer and get customer's feedback and confidence.
4. After implementation, you should create a Knowledge article, so that business can understand the effective use of the use case or need. Knowledge articles should be readable and sometimes use of context sensitive pictures and flow charts help users to the understand the context.
5. Easy access to the Knowledge article, so that when customer need it they will have it.
6. Engaging them in Chatter when you come up with this implementation.
7. Taking feedback periodically, how they are using this feature and what's their suggestions for future improvements.
8. Build continuous improvement process at your organization.